# Using a DLL created in Visual Studio with Qt

Tags: qt, dll

I have a DLL created in Visual Studio. It is for Peak USB to CAN device. This DLL is given by the vendor.

Now i want to use this DLL inside a Qt GUI. I am using default compiler of Qt to compile the Qt GUI application.

Is it possible to use this DLL created in Visual Studio directly inside Qt application?

What is exact procedure for this? I am doing it first time so please suggest.

Do gui & dll have to be compiled with same compiler to use properly?

Edit :
**how can i confirm** what i have installed .. means **what compiler is used by QT on my PC** ?
 i have installed using following `offline` installer **QtSdk-offline-win-x86-v1_2_1.exe** is it MSVC specific ?

Comment: When you are writing on this site, `backticks` are meant to signify code. Please do not use them for other stuff. If you want to add emphasis, you can use one or two asterisks to get *italic* or **bold**.

Answer (score 2):

With "default compiler of Qt" you probably mean mingw.

Using MSVC-compiled DLLs will not work then. DLLs compiled from C++ with MingW and MSVC are ABI-incompatible to each other, i.e. cannot be mixed (plain C libraries work though).

I suggest to download Qt for MSVC and use that.

Comment: how can i confirm what i have installed .. means what compiler is used by QT on my PC... i have installed using following offline installer ---- QtSdk-offline-win-x86-v1_2_1.exe --- is it MSVC specific ? please confirm.

Comment: I'm rather sure that comes with mingw, but you should be able to see the configured compiler in the list of available Qt's and/or the Kit configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and I have done it before.  I am assuming you are talking about a Win32 DLL, probably written in C.  Using any language other than C could be tricky.

I don't remember the exact procedure but here is the outline:

1. Configure your QT app to link to the .lib (import library binary) for the DLL.  I think you need to edit the main QMake config file.
2. Add an include in your Qt app for the DLL's header (.h) file.
3. Add a Qt post-build step to copy that DLL to your app directory so it can be found and loaded at runtime.

Comment: Do gui & dll have to be compiled with same compiler to use properly ?

Comment: No, we wrote a C DLL with Visual Studio (Microsoft's compiler) and used it in Qt (MinGW).  C++ would probably not work.

Comment: Katoch, first you should just figure out how to call a function in a Visual Studio C++ DLL from Qt.  The functions should be `extend "C"` and I think `__stdcall` also.  After that, I would edit that C++ DLL to be a wrapper around the third-party C++ DLL you have, exposing any of the particular functionality that you need.

Comment: **how can i confirm** what i have installed .. means **what compiler is used by QT on my PC** ?

 i have installed using following `offline` installer **QtSdk-offline-win-x86-v1_2_1.exe** is it MSVC specific ?

Answer (score 0):

use `QLibrary`. 
I tried **Qt()** to call **DLL(FORTRAN)**. it works well.
wish it coud help